# Solving stochastic equation

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, random, stochastic-calculus, random-process

I am trying to solve, numerically, a classic stochastic Liouville's equation, namely

\begin{equation}
\frac{dA(t)}{dt} = -B(t)A(t)+ {\cal C}(t)
\end{equation}
with $B(t)=\cos(\omega t)$, and stochastic variable ${\cal C}$ satisfying $\left\langle {\cal C}(t){\cal C}(0)\right\rangle = {\cal C}_0 e^{-t/T}$.

Initially I started implement a "NDSolve" for that, together with a "WhenEvent"

```
Ca[t_] := 1/10 RandomReal[{-1, 1}];

sys = {D[A[t],t] == - Cos[w t]A[t]+ C[t], WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt], C[t] -> Ca[t]], A[0] == 1, C[0] == 0}; {s\[Rho]} = 

NDSolve[sys, {A,C}, {t, ti, tf},  DiscreteVariables -> {C[t]}
```

It works fine, but the random variable ${\cal C}$ does not have the stochastic properties I am looking for.
Is there any way to create a random variable like that in Mathematica, or is there any a routine for this type of stochastic equations or stochastic variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look into the ``ItoProcess[]``? I'm not super familiar with the topic, so I'm not sure how to define the noise with the specific correlation you need though.

Comment: Another possibility that just came to mind is to use the correct distribution in the ``Ca[t]`` function via ``RandomVariate[]``. I tried ``Ca[t_]:=RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/T]]``, but it doesn't seem to give the right correlation. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can shed some more light on this, I'm also eager to see the answer :-)